# Tracing mysql-java-connector errors

Tags: mysql, jdbc, birt

We are using BirtActuate in our application in showing reports.

```
Actuate -----> JDBC driver --------> MysqlDB
```

We are aiming to TRACE errors that appears while connecting via JDBC to mysql.

We have followed instructions available at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

and tried making connection using following connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1/TestDB?interactiveClient=true&autoReconnect=true&profileSQL=true&traceProtocol=true
```

As per the documentation of `logger` parameter in link mentioned we found that

> The name of a class that implements "com.mysql.jdbc.log.Log" that will
>   be used to log messages to. (default is
>   "com.mysql.jdbc.log.StandardLogger", which logs to STDERR)

We want to trap all errors in a file so we can send that to support people to help us solving issues. I do not really know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `&profileSQL=true&traceProtocol=true` to JDBC connection URL will cause extra traces to be logged by the BirtActuate's default's logger in directory which in present birtActuateServer is `$BIRT_HOME/server/data/logs`

Go to the logs directory and run on command prompt

```
> grep -rl com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions .
```

This command should list the files in which it has found "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions" string